# Add a custom filed to fastapi responce model (serializers)

Tags: python, fastapi

I'm following [this guide](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/) from the Fastapi documentation and I have a question what if want to add a custom field when I return an object from DB. In Django I can use serializers.

**My case:**
I want to save an image name into DB, but before that I need save an actual file in a static folder. When I call GET /items/1 I want to return not just an image name from DB, but full URL, so I need to execute some logic on every request in order to build the URL. The question is how can I achieve that? The only thing I can think of is to add an additional DTO layer that coverts input data to Pydantic classes, so it's gonna be:
DTO class -> Pydantic -> DB

Is there more fancy way of doing that?

**Code example:**

schemas.py

```
from typing import List, Literal, Optional
from enum import Enum, IntEnum

from pydantic import BaseModel, constr, validator

class Ingredient(BaseModel):
    quantity: int
    quantityUnit: QuantityUnitEnum
    name: constr(max_length=50)

class RecipeBase(BaseModel):
    id: int = None
    title: constr(max_length=50)
    # image_name: str

    @validator('ingredients')
    def ingredients_must_have_unique_name(cls, values):
        names = []
        for item in values:
            names.append(item.name)
        if len(names) > len(set(names)):
            raise ValueError('must contain unique names')
        return values


class RecipeCreate(RecipeBase):
    pass


class Recipe(RecipeBase):
    id: int

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

model.py

```
class Recipe(Base):
    __tablename__ = "recipes"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    title = Column(String(50), index=True, nullable=False)
    image_name = Column(String(50), index=True, nullable=False)
```

main.py

```
@app.post("/recipes", response_model=schemas.Recipe)
def create_recipe(recipe: schemas.RecipeCreate, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    return repository.create_recipe(db=db, recipe=recipe)
    
    
@app.get("/recipes/{recipe_id}", response_model=schemas.Recipe)
def get_recipe(recipe_id, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    return repository.get_recipe(db, recipe_id=recipe_id)
```

repository.py

```
def get_recipe(db: Session, recipe_id: int):
    return db.query(models.Recipe).get(recipe_id)
```

Comment: There is nothing stopping your service layer / controller to using `from_orm` directly to construct the pydantic version of your db object; you can then populate the `.url` field yourself. You should also be able to use a `@property` decorated method in your db object, or you could use a `@validator` in your pydantic class. If you could add a minimal example of what you want to achieve and with what models, it might be easier to give you a better answer.

Comment: Right, so I added not an additional level, but a DTO model. Inspired by this article https://khalilstemmler.com/articles/typescript-domain-driven-design/repository-dto-mapper/ decided to implement DDD approach